# What is row major and column major in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, row-major-order

I am new to numpy and i was reading numpy but i am not able to understand row major and column major in numpy can anyone explain with example with easiest way? Any answer would be appreciated thanks

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order

Comment: The default in `numpy` is row-major, or what's also call `order='C'`.  There's a lot you can do without fiddling with the `order`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider an array such as this:

```
>>> A = np.random.randint(low=1, high=9, size=(3,3))
>>> A   
array([[8, 7, 2],
       [4, 2, 5],
       [8, 6, 7]])
```

Using *row-major* means the values would be stored in memory like this (assuming 64-bit integers):

```
Memory address  0x00  0x08  0x10  0x18  0x20  0x28  0x30  0x38  0x40
Value              8     7     2     4     2     5     8     6     7
```

Whereas *column-major* storage would look like this:

```
Memory address  0x00  0x08  0x10  0x18  0x20  0x28  0x30  0x38  0x40
Value              8     4     8     7     2     6     2     5     7
```

Numpy stores in row-major order by default.

```
>>> A[0].__array_interface__['data']
(14502656, False)
>>> A[1].__array_interface__['data']
(14502680, False)  # 14502680 - 14502656 == 24
```

You can see the second row of data is 24 bytes (three int64 worth) away from the first.  The transposed array offers a view into the original array data, not a copy, which is *strided* in a way that appears column major (the actual data in memory remains the same order):

```
>>> A.T[0].__array_interface__['data']
(14502656, False)
>>> A.T[1].__array_interface__['data']
(14502664, False)  # 14502664 - 14502656 == 8
```